# html5 regex for a capitalized first letter

Tags: regex, html

Is it possible to use HMTL5 patterns to verify that the first letter of a string is capitalized? I looked on http://html5pattern.com/ and on Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything. I also am not familiar enough with REGEXs to try to  create my own. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to only cover the English language, the task looks trivial. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
[A-Z].+
```